# full width, limited height image while maintaining aspect ratio

Tags: image, css

I'm trying to recreate an image to look like the cover image [here](http://www.fastcolabs.com/). The image has to be the full width of the browser but still maintaining a certain fixed height. With all that, it must still maintain aspect ratio.

Setting `width: 100%; height: auto;` makes the image full-width with the right aspect ratio. However, the height is off. If I set `width: 100%; max-height: 300px;`, the aspect ratio is lost.

I'm sure it's possible (see link above) but I just can't figure out how to get this result. Would appreciate some pointers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to "cut" the part of the image that exceeds the fixed height. So set this styling to the parent container of the image:

```
#image-container { height: 300px; overflow:hidden; }
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NKUyh/5/)

Comment: I've tried this but I was wondering if its possible to get the image in full still?

Comment: @stefanie: You want images to have `fixed height`, a `fluid 100% width` and keep their `aspect-ratio`. You think that this is possible?